# Lucene search special character

Tags: java, lucene

In my Lucene index I store names with special characters (e.g. Savić) in a field like the one described below.

```
FieldType fieldType = new Field();
fieldType.setStored(true);
fieldType.setIndexed(true);
fieldType.setTokenized(false);<br>
new Field("NAME", "Savić".toLowerCase(), fieldType);
```

I use a StopwordAnalyzerBase analyzer and Lucene Version.LUCENE_45.

If I search in the field exactly for "savić" it doesn't find it. How to deal with the special characters?

```
@Override
protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(final String fieldName, final Reader reader) {
PatternTokenizer src;
// diese Zeichen werden nicht als Trenner verwendet
src = new PatternTokenizer(reader, Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[^§/_&äÄöÖüÜßéèàáîâêûôëïñõãçœ◊]]"), -1);

TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, src);
tok = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, tok);
tok = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tok, TRIBUNA_WORDS_SET);

return new TokenStreamComponents(src, tok) {
    @Override
    protected void setReader(final Reader reader) throws IOException {
        super.setReader(reader);
    }
};
```

}

Comment: `StopwordAnalyzerBase` is abstract.  Implementations of it are quite varied, and include most of the commonly used analyzers.  Are you using a custom implementation of it as your analyzer, or what?

Comment: Sorry for beeing nonspecific. Yes I use a custom implementation which basically just extends the StopwordAnalyzerBase.

Comment: What does your `CreateComponents` do?

Comment: @femtoRgon I added the createComponents method to the post. Thank you in advance! I'm an absolute newbie to Lucene and really lost.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices:

1. Try adding an [ASCIIFoldingFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/ASCIIFoldingFilter.html):

   ```
   src = new PatternTokenizer(reader, Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[^§/_&äÄöÖüÜßéèàáîâêûôëïñõãçœ◊]]"), -1);

   TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, src);
   tok = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, tok);
   tok = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(tok);
   tok = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tok, TRIBUNA_WORDS_SET);
   ```

   This will take a fairly simplistic approach of reducing non-ASCII characters, such as Ä, to their best match in ASCII characters (A, in this case), if a reasonable ASCII alternative character exists.  It won't do anything fancy with trying to use language-specific intelligence to determine the best replacements though.
2. For something more linguistically intelligent, there are tools to handle this sort of thing in many of the language-specific packages.  The [GermanNormalizationFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanNormalizationFilter.html) would be one example, which will do similar things to the ASCIIFoldingFilter, but will apply the rules in a way that is appropriate to the German language, such as 'ß' being replaced by 'ss'.  You'd use it similar to the above code:

   ```
   src = new PatternTokenizer(reader, Pattern.compile("[\\W&&[^§/_&äÄöÖüÜßéèàáîâêûôëïñõãçœ◊]]"), -1);

   TokenStream tok = new StandardFilter(matchVersion, src);
   tok = new LowerCaseFilter(matchVersion, tok);
   tok = new GermanNormalizationFilter(tok);
   tok = new StopFilter(matchVersion, tok, TRIBUNA_WORDS_SET);
   ```

Comment: I assume that if I use such a filter this will replace for example the ć from Savić with a normal c and If I search for "Savic" then it will find all Savic and Savić. Let's say I have 10 Savić in my index and 5 Savic. If I search for "Savić" (exact match) I want to find the 10 Savić with the weird c and if I search for "Savic" I only want to find the 5 Savic without the weird c. Do I have to change the query to achieve this and leave the index as it is? Thx.